# Perl Range Operator with Letters and Numbers

Tags: perl

Is there a way to use Perl's range operator `..` to use letters AND numbers?

For example, have:

```
for my $i ('X'..'9') {
    print "$i ";
}
```

output `X Y Z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not unless `for my $i ('X' .. 'Z', 1 .. 9)` counts. "Z" will never increment to 1.